# How do I efficiently create closed shapes with shared boundaries in Inkscape, e.g. countries on a map?

Tags: inkscape, path

In the drawing you see five paths (orange, pink, green, blue, and red), which define the boundaries of 4 regions (a, b, c, and d).  I now want to create those regions so they are fillable, and without crazy “op-art” effects due to differing directions. For instance, to create region b, I need to use the pink path (which is shared with c), the green path (shared with a) and part of the blue path (shared with d).

What is a process for doing this that is efficient?  My actual drawing has dozens of regions and I'd like a process that doesn't take a week.[image: paths before making into regions]

Comment: If each shared border was one single path, with no gaps obviously, then it would be possible to use the technique described in the [question I answered here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116778/does-something-like-illustrators-shape-builder-exist-in-inkscape/116788#116788). But you would have to cut up some of the paths at the interesctions in your design first before doing that.

Comment: Here's a [proof of concept](https://imgur.com/a/YLjEhGe) showing how the technique in the other answer works, on a similar design problem.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you.... feel free to do it as an actual answer and I'll accept.  You saved me a ton of time.

Comment: OK I will add it as an answer now.

Comment: http://www.karmatics.com/stuff/stackexchange.svg

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each shared border was one single path, with no gaps obviously, then it would be possible to use the technique described in the [question I answered here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116778/does-something-like-illustrators-shape-builder-exist-in-inkscape/116788#116788). So, to do that, you would have to cut up some of the paths at the intersctions in your design first before doing that.

Here's a proof of concept showing how the technique in the other answer works on a similar design problem

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution. I did your approach on my sample geometry and it is here: http://www.karmatics.com/stuff/stackexchange.svg

Answer (score 1):

With Inkscape 1. (now: 1.2), just use the tool that fills any closed area : **Bucket Fill Tool** (3rd from the bottom on the screenshot)
Il will fill the closed area defined by any number of lines, and behind the scene it creates the corresponding polygon. To let it appear more clearly as an independent entity, just define a stroke color ; you can treat it like any other path (move it...).

[image: polygon created by bucket fill tool from independent lines]