# Align 2 closed shapes that share some curves

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My problem is similar to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118371/how-do-i-efficiently-create-closed-shapes-with-shared-boundaries-in-inkscape-e), but I'm using Ilustrator 26.0

I have 2 **closed** shapes that share a bondary.

This was achieved after "dividing" several overlapping shapes and doing some editing, I end up with shapes that share a bondary but the bondaries curves are not identical.

Is there a ease way of making those bondaries exactly the same but keeping the 2 closed separated shapes?

here is a print:
[image]

and here is the bondary at 1600% zoom:
[image]

Comment: delete the shorter segments edges. use shapebuilder click on both areas. Anyway due to mis-implemented rendering engines you may in fact want to avoid doing this.

Comment: As Joojaa eludes.. it's actually *better* to have shapes overlap in may instances.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you (both) elaborate?

Comment: See here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches and here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg

Comment: In any event, if you want perfectly aligned sides like that, make one path overlap the other, then select both and use Shape Builder to remove the overlap portions. What's left will align as close as it can be aligned.

Comment: Thanks, it works with Shape Builder. The reason I want perfect overlapping is that  I will plasma cut it from different materials and assemble it.

Comment: @FernandoFabreti note that beziers cannot be exactly same unless they share the same points. Shapebuilder should do this if the order is correct. But verify or insert a point. Anyway this probably does not matter your machines kerf and tolerance is more than that.

Comment: Thanks, yes kerf will compensate for the errors, I guess. I'll cut exactly over the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to overlap the shapes.

Then utilizing the **Shape Builder Tool** remove the overlap (by uniting it with one side). The result will be two shapes which are aligned as close as they can be aligned.