# Bucket fills leave a gap with boundaries in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am using `Inkscape 1.0` on Kubuntu 20.04. I have an area with boundaries where I chose to `bucket fill`. It works fine, but there is a distinct gap between the boundaries and the filled area. In case of corner, it is a fillet than a pointed edge. Please see the image below

[image]

Can we overcome this limitation somehow ? Any help will be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the threshold setting to something like 80, before you fill. You may have to adjust this value as it will depend on the thickness and colour of the strokes, too much and it will likely fill over the strokes.
2. You can also increase the grow/shrink amount to something like 0.5px
3. This may result in slightly rounded corners, but you can select the fill, then send the it to the bottom of the object stack using <kbd>End</kbd>, so that the stroke above will hide the defect.

Example

[image]

Ultimately, using the Bucket Fill is a quick and dirty fix, but it's less than ideal because it relies on the image as it is rendered on-screen. It's better to better to make your designs with closed paths which can then be filled by setting a fill attribute in the Fill and Stroke panel. Using this method, a fill will fit right up to the stroke without the mess.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any method from the OP image that we can extract the " other " part of the boundary ? In some use cases, the " rest of the " boundaries are either too complex or hard to draw using a bezier.

Comment: I tried the answer. But with threshold at 80 and grow/shrink at 0.5 bucket fill completely ignores the drawn boundary and goes on filling the whole shape. I then reset it to defaults and now I get to fill through the drawn area. Thanks.

Comment: @user68592 You may have to adjust the threshold depending on the thickness of the strokes. 80 is merely a suggestion. As to your first comment, that's really a different question entirely. Making fillable closed paths from complex overlapping lines is possible. [There's an answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116778/does-something-like-illustrators-shape-builder-exist-in-inkscape/116788#116788) that might help.

Comment: Threshold of 20 works for me. And additional answer helps as well. Thanks.