# Filling in Inkscape causes some padding

Tags: inkscape

I wanted to fill a shape which I draw by adding some lines in InkScape:

[image]

In spite I have set *Close gaps* options to None.

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

But without the lines and without those white gaps shown above. Lines are only used for guidance the filling, but I don't want to bother coloring the lines, as for more complex situations the lines would have to be multicolored.

What to do if I want to achieve more extreme filling like this:

[image]

Comment: The fill tool does its work only in screen resolution. For the best fill tool accuracy zoom in to the biggest image size which  fits to your screen. It's still inaccurate, but it can be good enough. I use it often when the borders are free hand drawings. To get geometrically exact fills do not use the fill tool. Instead combine paths and use boolean operations. But that's already said in the given answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Bucket Fill tool for this.

1. Draw a circle with the Ellipse tool
2. Draw a triangle shape with the Bézier tool (aka Pen tool)
3. Select each shape, and apply the desired fill in the Fill and Stroke dialog <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Click on the fill tab. Add a fill. You can also change the stroke in this dialog.

Example

[image]

**EDIT**

For designs that are more complex, it's probably better to use boolean operations to create fillable shapes.  [See this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116778/does-something-like-illustrators-shape-builder-exist-in-inkscape/116788#116788) about possible methods.

Comment: Please see my edit. I just brought the simple circle and triangle to provide a basic easy example.

Comment: @Daniel - see my edit - I mention another answer I gave here to make fillable shapes. No need to use the bucket fill tool at all.  The bucket fill tool is not a good way to do this.